# How to create a meeting using the zoom api

Tags: node.js, zoom-sdk

I'm looking at the zoom api documentation. I created an app that allows patients to set up appointments with doctors. Everything is virtual. I need to setup time with the doctor and create a zoom meeting link. i looked at the API https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/meetingCreate

Where it asks for a userid as a path parameter, what user id should I pass in? Should the doctors be providing their zoom email address? or should it be my zoom username? If the doctor's have to pass in their email address, do I need to authenticate using oauth2 to get access to their zoom to create meetings on their behalf. Is there a way I can circumvent that and use my username? However, the issue is that there might be multiple meetings at the same time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have to first register your app with Zoom market place. To register into Zoom market place, you have to login in zoom with a valid email id. Once you register successfully, you will get API Key and secret Key, these will be used in your NodeJs code to interact with zoom api. Here, you have to pass the same email id with which you have registered your app with zoom market place. You can take reference from below blogs:

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting.html

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting_18.html